# gulp время от времени глючит

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm, pug, stylus

https://prnt.sc/jhuoza

https://pastebin.com/A5ZLshgW

gulp стал подглючивать на домашнем компе (на рабочем всё норм), не знаю что делать. Какое-то время всё нормально, потом выплёвывает кучу вот таких одинаковых задач и зависает. Спустя какое-то время отмирает и снова работает до следующего зависона. Причём так происходит даже когда я ничего не делаю, просто простаивает комп с запущенным процессом. Помню только что обновил npm, но это же врятли?

1. Можно ли как-то отловить что он в этот момент делает? Лог какой вывести. Ошибок в консоль не выдаёт, пытается упасть, но спустя время оправляется. Может просто порт не может с другой программой поделить, которая внезапно проснулась и стучится в интернет?
2. Гугл спрашивал различным сочетанием слов на русском и английском, ничего похожего не нашёл.
3. Может ещё какие данные нужны? Предоставлю. Хотя если у кого было, по фотке можно узнать проблему, ни с чем не спутать.

Comment: если вы нашли баг в гулпе, то вы можете сабмиттить его в репозитарий. вы никогда не поймете что у вас глючит пока не определите причину.

Comment: Как определить причину некорректного поведения галпа?

Comment: вы не можете писать вопрос если вы не определили причину.

Comment: Знал бы причину, сам бы исправил, лол. Я и пишу, может у кого подобное было, чтобы узнать причину. Или хотя бы подсказать как искать ответ, гуглёж не помог.

Comment: не такое тут не работает, хотя как знать может быть кто-то ответит на такое

Comment: Вы хотябы `gulpfile` в вопрос прикрепите, как понять причину, если нет кода? Пол года назад я работал с `gulp` иногда были проблемы, но все эти проблемы были следствием ошибок в коде `gulpfile`

Comment: Вот: https://pastebin.com/A5ZLshgW